# DataGrid blank/not displaying data? Material UI

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datagrid

For some reason my DataGrid table is not displaying anything.

[Example of my data and DataGrid not displaying anything in new project with source code from below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDYDq.png)

I had this issue happen in my previous project and I thought it was something I did when trying to learn everything so I made another project, setup reactjs and material ui and tried again and had the same issue.

I made a bug report on GitHub but I am really looking for a quick solution. Does anyone have any ideas? Everything in my project has been updated to the latest version (including django and mui libraries)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid'


function WatcherOverview() {
    
      const columns = [
        { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90 },
        {
          field: 'firstName',
          headerName: 'First name',
          width: 150,
          editable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'lastName',
          headerName: 'Last name',
          width: 150,
          editable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'age',
          headerName: 'Age',
          type: 'number',
          width: 110,
          editable: true,
        },
        {
          field: 'fullName',
          headerName: 'Full name',
          description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
          sortable: false,
          width: 160,
          valueGetter: (params) =>
            `${params.row.firstName || ''} ${params.row.lastName || ''}`,
        },
      ];
      
      const rows = [
        { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
        { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
        { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
        { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
        { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
        { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
        { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
        { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
        { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
      ];

      return (
        <Container>
          <h1>Single items:</h1>
          <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
        </Container>
      );
    }

export default WatcherOverview
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the `autoHeight` props in DataGrid. if you want more granule control over height. then check `headerHeight` and `rowHeight` on https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/

```
<DataGrid
  ...
  autoHeight
/>
```

also if you don't want to use autoHeight in DataGrid then you need to specify height in container. https://mui.com/components/data-grid/layout/

```
<Container sx={{height: 350}}>
  ...
   <DataGrid
      ...
   />
</Container>
```

also you can use `headerHeight` and `rowHeight` for more granule control.

```
<Container sx={{height: 350}}>
  ...
  <DataGrid
    ...
    headerHeight={75}
    rowHeight={65}
  />
</Container>
```